# Woocommerce coupons adding custom checkbox

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I've gotten far enough on this simple function in functions.php that let's me add a checkbox to coupons. However, once I save/update a coupon, my checkbox value (check/unchecked) doesn't get committed (so the checkbox is always unchecked). In other words, I can't get it to update the value to yes in the meta_value column in postmetas when I update/save. The checkbox is there, I just can't use it... highly frustrating! Any sugestions on what I'm doing wrong, please :)

```
function add_coupon_revenue_dropdown_checkbox() { 
$post_id = $_GET['post'];

woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array( 'id' => 'include_stats', 'label' => __( 'Coupon check list', 'woocommerce' ), 'description' => sprintf( __( 'Includes the coupon in coupon check drop-down list', 'woocommerce' ) ) ) );

$include_stats = isset( $_POST['include_stats'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';

update_post_meta( $post_id, 'include_stats', $include_stats );

do_action( 'woocommerce_coupon_options_save', $post_id );

}add_action( 'woocommerce_coupon_options', 'add_coupon_revenue_dropdown_checkbox', 10, 0 );
```

The part I'm trying to affect is:

wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-coupon-data.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are attempting to save the value of the checkbox in the same function where you generate the html for it. This won't work. You need to break your current function into two parts that run on two different WooCommerce hooks.

The first is to display the actual checkbox:

```
function add_coupon_revenue_dropdown_checkbox() { 
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array( 'id' => 'include_stats', 'label' => __( 'Coupon check list', 'woocommerce' ), 'description' => sprintf( __( 'Includes the coupon in coupon check drop-down list', 'woocommerce' ) ) ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_coupon_options', 'add_coupon_revenue_dropdown_checkbox', 10, 0 );
```

The second is to save the value of the checkbox when the submitted form is being processed.

```
function save_coupon_revenue_dropdown_checkbox( $post_id ) {
    $include_stats = isset( $_POST['include_stats'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'include_stats', $include_stats );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_coupon_options_save', 'save_coupon_revenue_dropdown_checkbox');
```

Comment: haha, posted my answer before I saw yours! Yes, I understand the process now. Thank you for your answer  :)